# Automatic method delegation in Python

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I have a rather contrived code here :

```
backend_data = {
    "admins": ["Leo", "Martin", "Thomas", "Katrin"],
    "members": [
        "Leo",
        "Martin",
        "Thomas",
        "Katrin",
        "Subhayan",
        "Clemens",
        "Thoralf"
    ],
    "juniors": ["Orianne", "Antonia", "Sarah"]
}

class Backend:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.backend_data = data
        
    def get_all_admins(self):
        return self.backend_data.get("admins")
    
    def get_all_members(self):
        return self.backend_data.get("members")
    
    def get_all_juniors(self):
        return self.backend_data.get("juniors")
    
    
class BackendAdaptor:
    # Does some conversion and validation
    def __init__(self, backend):
        self.backend = backend
        
    def get_all_admins(self):
        return (admin for admin in self.backend.get_all_admins())
    
    def get_all_members(self):
        return (member for member in self.backend.get_all_members() if member not in self.backend.get_all_admins())
    
    def get_all_juniors(self):
        return (junior for junior in self.backend.get_all_juniors())
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    backend = Backend(data=backend_data)
    adaptor = BackendAdaptor(backend=backend)
    print(f"All admins are : {list(adaptor.get_all_admins())}")
    print(f"All members are : {list(adaptor.get_all_members())}")
    print(f"All juniors are : {list(adaptor.get_all_juniors())}")
```

So the `BackendAdaptor` class basically would be used to do some validation and conversion of the data that we get from the `Backend` .

The client should only be asked to interact with the API of the `BackendAdaptor` which is exactly similar to that of `Backend` . The adaptor class sits in middle and gets data from `Backend` does some validation if required and the gives back the data to client.

The issue is that the validation on the data that is getting returned from the `Backend` is not done for every method(For ex: there is validation done on `get_all_members` but not on `get_all_admins` and also not on `get_all_juniors`). The method just gives back a generator on whatever data it gets from `Backend`.

As is the case now i still have to implement a one liner methods for them .

Is there a way in Python to avoid this ? I am thinking in lines of magic methods like `__getattribute__` ? But i have no idea on how to do this for methods.

So the best case scenario is this:

1. I implement the methods for which i know that i have to do some validation on `Backend` data
2. For the rest of the methods it is automatically delegated to `Backend` and then i just return a generator from what i get back

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `__getattr__`. It is only called if a non-existing attribute is accessed. This will return some generic function with the desired functionality.

```
class BackendAdaptor:
    def __init__(self, backend):
        self.backend = backend
    
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if not hasattr(self.backend, name):
            raise AttributeError(f"'{name}' not in backend.")
        return lambda: (i for i in getattr(self.backend, name)())

    def get_all_members(self):
        return (member for member in self.backend.get_all_members() if member not in self.backend.get_all_admins())
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer but how do i make it to call a function with some parameters ? In my simple case the function does not have any parameters but what if the functions have ? Can you give me some hints ?

Comment: `lambda *args: (i for i in getattr(self.backend, name)(*args))` to delegate the arguments to the backend method. You can also define and return a normal function inside the `__getattr__` method, if the logic gets to much for a lambda function.